# Verilog CMOS OR gate error

Tags: verilog, digital

in cmd it shows me y=z how to fix it. what is worng with my code?
I want to get a=1 b=1 y= what? not z.

See screen below:

[image: screen]

This is my code

```
module or2(input a, b, output y);

  nmos(wire1,a,b);
  pmos(wire1,0,b);
  pmos(y,a,b);

endmodule

module OR_tb();
  reg a,b;
  wire y;

  or2 dut(a, b, y);

  initial
    begin
      $monitor("a = %b b = %b y = %b",a,b,y);
      a=0;  
      b=0;
      #1; b=1;
      #1; a=1; b=0;
      #1; b=1; 
      #1;
      $finish;
    end

endmodule
```

Comment: Google 'OR gate cmos' and you will see that your `or2` module is wrong: it should have 6 transistors in it.

Comment: So, I need to increase pmods and nmods?

Comment: I think so. I don't know much about transistor-level design, but I know that the simplest 2-input gate to input is a NAND gate and that requires 4 transistors and, as i say, a quick bit of googling revealed a CMOS OR gate needs 6.

Answer (score 0):

`or2` module is wrong. Here is the `or2` module.

```
module or2(input a, b, output y);
  wire wire1, temp_out;

  // 2 Bit NOR Gate
  nmos(temp_out, 1'b0, a);
  nmos(temp_out, 1'b0, b);

  pmos(wire1, 1'b1, a);
  pmos(temp_out, wire1, b);

  // 1 Bit Inverter
  nmos(out, 1'b0, temp_out);
  pmos(out, 1'b1, temp_out);
endmodule
```